# Create Multiple Files Using Base XML File with ID in Lookup XML File

Tags: c#, xml

I have Base File and Look-Up File with ID as a common Attribute in both the files.
    I want to write C# Code to Read Base File with ID look into Look-Up File based on Subscribers, create 2 XML files with file names _USA and _CAD as suffixes

Base File:

```
Base File Name : Base_File.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Publication >
    <Payload >
        <BaseList >
<Base>
  <Custom>
    <CustomE>
      <ML_BUY_SELL_FLAG>false</ML_BUY_SELL_FLAG>
      <ID_BB_GLOBAL_PARENT_COMPANY_NAME>First Trust /USA</ID_BB_GLOBAL_PARENT_COMPANY_NAME>
    </CustomE>
  </Custom>
  <Identifier>
    <ID>10072271</ID>
  </Identifier>
  </Base>
  <Base>
  <Custom>
    <CustomE>
      <ML_BUY_SELL_FLAG>false</ML_BUY_SELL_FLAG>
      <ID_BB_GLOBAL_PARENT_COMPANY_NAME>First Trust /CAD</ID_BB_GLOBAL_PARENT_COMPANY_NAME>
    </CustomE>
  </Custom>
  <Identifier>
    <ID>10072272</ID>
  </Identifier>
  </Base>
  </BaseList>
  </Payload>
</Publication>
```

Look-Up file:

```
Look-Up File Name: LookUp.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Publication >
    <Payload >
        <SubsList >
            <Subscription>
                <ID>10072271</ID>
                <Subscribers>
                    <Subscriber>USA</Subscriber>
                  </Subscribers>
                  </Subscription>
                <Subscription>
                <ID>10072272</ID>
                <Subscribers>
                    <Subscriber>CAD</Subscriber>
                    </Subscribers>
            </Subscription>      
        </SubsList>
    </Payload>
</Publication>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread your questions. Right now your posting is very hard to understand. Please also provide code. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: The base file is confusing.  You say you want "TWO FILES".  I think you mean two elements.  Are there always going to be two IDs in both files?

Comment: My Base file can have n number of IDs with each ID Data between tags of <Base>and </Base>. Lookup File ID Can have max 3 Subscribers. Let me Put different way, My Base file have 100 IDs with Data, My lookup have only 50 IDs but USA & CAD Subscribers. I have to create 2 Base files with 50 IDs with data info.. this should only done by lookup